# Grub not showing after dual booting ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I have an acer laptop and after dual-booting, it brings me back immediately to windows. When I check the bootloader, Ubuntu is not there. I've also tried using the command

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

But it still doesn't work. So I tried to use the boot-repair tool in the 'Try Ubuntu option' instead of installing it again. It still doesn't work and tells me to post this for reference.

http://paste2.org/4dyvN6UI

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Is secure boot enabled? (If it is you should disable it)

Comment: Isn't it suppose to work even with secure boot enabled?

Answer (score 0):

I remember getting this error whenever there was some sort of Windows update.

I solved it by booting into Ubuntu live USB, and do:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Additionally, you can check out this solution from windows: https://itsfoss.com/no-grub-windows-linux/